# Do I have to call TlsAlloc() in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH?

Tags: winapi

Do I have to call TlsAlloc() in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH once genrally since the DLL hasn't any addional calls with DLL_THREAD_ATTACH for the thread doing the LoadLibrary() ?
Or to make it even more complicated: Do I get a DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notification in addition to the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH notification if I create a thread directly from DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH ?

**EDIT**: I've wrote a little test application that loads a library that spawns a thread:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HMODULE hmLib = LoadLibraryA( "theDll.dll" );
    HANDLE &hDllThread = *(HANDLE *)GetProcAddress( hmLib, "hDllThread" );
    WaitForSingleObject( hDllThread, INFINITE );
    cout << "thead terminated " << endl;
    cout << "thread id: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl << endl;
}
```

Here's the DLL:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport)
HANDLE hDllThread = NULL;

void printThreadId()
{
    cout << "thread id: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;
};

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch( dwReason )
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            printThreadId();
            cout << "process attach" << endl << endl;
            ::hDllThread = CreateThread( nullptr, 0,
                []( LPVOID ) -> DWORD
                {
                    cout << "created thread id: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    return 0;
                }, nullptr, 0, nullptr );
            // don't do that here
            // WaitForSingleObject( ::hDllThread, INFINITE );
            break;
        }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        printThreadId();
        cout << "thread attach" << endl << endl;
        // don't do that here
        // WaitForSingleObject( ::hDllThread, INFINITE );
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        printThreadId();
        cout << "thread detach" << endl << endl;
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        printThreadId();
        cout << "process detach" << endl << endl;
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

static struct S
{
    S()
    {
        printThreadId();
        cout << "statics are initialized, but not thread locals" << endl << endl;
    }
} s;
```

On my computer this prints:

```
thread id: 14692
statics are initialized, but not thread locals

thread id: 14692
process attach

thread id: 9396
thread attach

created thread id: 9396

thread id: 9396
thread detach

thead terminated
thread id: 14692

thread id: 14692
process detach
```

"thread attach" is printed before "created thread" *in the context of the new thread*. If I wait for the thread to terminate in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH or DLL_THREAD_ATTACH I wait forever. So the entry point is called after both calls. Is this documented ?

Comment: The thread is created, and the DLL entry point is called, before CreateThread returns, that's all.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: My output shows that the enty point is called *after* DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, where the thread is created, and *after* DLL_THREAD_ATTACH! If I wait for the thead to terminate with DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH or DLL_THREAD_ATTACH I wait forever and the entry point is _never_ called.

Comment: This question is not very clear to me.

What do you mean by "Do I have to call TlsAlloc() in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH?".

What do you mean by "So the entry point is called after both calls"? By entry point, do you mean DllMain?

What do you mean by "My output shows that the enty point is called after DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, where the thread is created, and after DLL_THREAD_ATTACH!". 

Have you looked at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain

Comment: @JonathanPotter- *the DLL entry point is called, before `CreateThread` returns, that's all.* this is of course wrong and can not be - first `CreateThread` return, current thread leave critical section and only after this new thread can call DLL entry point

Comment: *Do I have to call TlsAlloc() in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH once genrally* - yes, if you need only 1 index

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, everything I told based on outdated informaton. Before Vista dynamially loaded DLLs with thread locals weren't reliable.
Everything is fine with thread_local / __declspec(thread) in DLLs for years.

Answer (score 0):

1.`Do I have to call TlsAlloc() in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH once genrally since the DLL hasn't any addional calls with DLL_THREAD_ATTACH for the thread doing the LoadLibrary() ?`

[Call TlsAlloc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-thread-local-storage-in-a-dynamic-link-library) won't do anything for your current question.

> Each time the process creates a new thread, the entry-point function
> is called with the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH value.

---

2.`So the entry point is called after both calls. Is this documented ?`

**Raymond Chen** has explained thread creation and running process in [his blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283).

> When you call CreateThread, a kernel thread object is created and
> scheduled. Once the thread gets a chance to run, the kernel calls all
> the DllMain functions with the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH code. Once that’s
> done, the thread’s entry point is called.

In MSDN, You can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain#parameters).

> **DLL_THREAD_ATTACH,** Note that a DLL's entry-point function is called with this value only by threads created after the DLL is loaded by the
> process.

Comment: The last statement doesn't make any statements on threads that are created within a DllMain() part. But I think the mentioned feature that a thread created from DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH isn't scheduled before its DLL_THREAD_ATTACH is called doesn't exist by accident and is therefore reliable.